# How to efficiently evaluate a series of methods and call the ones that are not False?

Tags: python, class, methods, conditional-statements

The class below gets a string as input and produces another string via the `answer()` method.

```
class Question:

    a = ["hello", "hi"]
    b = ["how are you", "how do you do"]
    c = ["how is the weather", "is it cold today"]

    def __init__(self, question):
        self.question = question

    def get_greeting(self):
        if self.question in Question.a:
            return "Hi There!"

    def get_health(self):
        if self.question in Question.b:
            return "I am fine"

    def get_weather(self):
        if self.question in Question.c:
            return "It is warm"

    def answer(self):

        if self.get_greeting():
            return self.get_greeting()
        elif self.get_health():
            return self.get_health()
        elif self.get_weather():
            return self.get_weather()
        else:
            return "I don't understand"

question = Question("how is the weather") 
print(question.answer()) # getting the output
```

To me the above is bad because the code inside `answer()` it's long and it calls each method twice.

Therefore, I came up with a "better" `answer()` method that calls the methods only once, but it's still a lot of if conditionals.

```
def answer(self):

    result = self.get_greeting()
    if result:
        return result

    result = self.get_health()
    if result:
        return result

    result = self.get_weather()
    if result:
        return result

    return "I don't understand"
```

I think there might be some other technique that I am missing here. Anyone can suggest something?

Answer (score 3):

The result of `or` is the left-hand operand if it's not "false-y", otherwise the right-hand operand.
It also evaluates the right-hand operand only when it's needed.

```
def answer(self):
    return self.get_greeting() \
        or self.get_health() \
        or self.get_weather() \
        or "I don't understand"
```

Comment: Very elegant! Would it still be your choice if we had 50 methods instead of just three as we do in this example?

Comment: In that case, I would first focus on why there is such an unreasonable amount of methods. There's very probably a better solution than a function chain.

Comment: This is for a chatbot I am making. The chatbot has to count for many scenarios. He has to check if the user is asking about the weather, the time, the latest news, the oil price, nearest barber, the meaning of a word, and so on. I can't think of a better way to do that than having a separate method for each of those checks.

Comment: I think a table could be a better solution. (You essentially have one already, with functions as ”keys”.)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a tuple of all methods and then call them until one returns something:

```
def answer(self):
    methods = (self.get_greeting, self.get_health, self.get_weather)
    for m in methods:
        res = m()
        if res:
            return res
    return "I don't understand"
```

**Edit**

If you really want to create a lot of methods and have your `answer()` function try them all without explicitly telling it, you can use this code:

```
def answer(self):
        getters = (v for k, v in self.__class__.__dict__.items() if k.startswith("get_"))
        for method in getters:
            res = method(self)
            if res:
                return res
        return "I don't understand"
```

**Edit 2**

If your system just gets a string as an input and generates predefined outputs from it, you may be able to simplify it quite a bit:

```
knowledge = [
    (["hello", "hi"], "Hi There"),
    (["how are you", "how do you do"], "I am fine"),
    (["how is the weather", "is it cold today"], "It is warm")
]

def answer(question):
    for inputs, answer in knowledge:
        if question in inputs:
            return answer
    return "I don't understand"

print(answer("hello"))
```

Using this approach, adding a new phrase to the chatbot is as easy as adding a line to the knowledge data structure.

Comment: I hope Python had a way to create the `methods` tuple automatically. I know I can use `dirs` but that returns the `object` methods as well and not just the ones I have defined in my class.